# Flutter: How configure ListView() to auto-scroll to bottom (as new children are added) except when momentarily scrolling up to view older children

Tags: flutter

(I'm using a ListView() to implement a little logging pane that shows my app events.)

I looked through the ListView() documentation and can't seem to find a property like **autoScrollUnlessBrowsing**. I need:

1. The ListView() to auto-scroll to bottom every time a new child is
   added (so I don't have to manually drag up to expose new app activity).
2. However, while I'm temporarily scrolling-up to view old activity I want auto-scrolling momentarily suspended (because it's annoying to have it **yank** scrolling to bottom interrupting what I'm trying to read).  After I'm done browsing, if I manually scroll back to the bottom I want to auto-scroll to re-enable.

```
ListView(
    autoScrollUnlessBrowsing: true,
    children: children),
```

It would be great if Flutter could add this but until then how could this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scroll controller for that.

Define a scroll controller inside your page.

```
   ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();
```

Then pass it to your listview widget. For example -

```
ListView.builder(
    controller: _controller,
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: (_, __) => ListTile(title: Text('demo')),
  )
```

Then in your child adding function, right after the child adding logic, put the following code for smooth scrolling to the end of the listview.

```
_controller.animateTo(
  _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);
```

your function will look something like this.

```
void addChild(){
   // put your adding child logic here
   _controller.animateTo(
    _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
     duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
     curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    );
}
```

We can also use `_controller.jumpTo()` for jumping to the end. But for smooth scrolling `_controller.animateTo()` is preferred.

But I would suggest adding the recently added children to the beginning of the list rather than adding it to the end. I mean rather than `list.add(element)`, use of `list.insert(0, element)` is preferred.

Comment: If you only want to scroll to the bottom of your list if you are currently close to the bottom (i.e. you are not browsing the list), you can add wrap the animateTo call in an if check: `if (_scrollController.position.pixels >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent * 0.8){_scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut,);}`